# How does one add mongodb and/or postgresql-extension plugins to Grails 3.0.0+?

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I played with Grails 3.0.0.M1 today and tried to make a small application using mongodb, however I couldn't manage to add it correctly to my build.gradle file. What is the correct syntax? I tried (excerpt):

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven { url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}


dependencies {
    //...
    compile ':mongodb:3.0.2'
    //...
}
```

as that plugin's documentation suggested, but ended up with it not being found. I also noted that the `grailsCentral()` shortcut didn't work.

I then tried to add postgresql-extensions, but it was the same. Has the syntax changed, are these plugins not supported at the time, or what gives?

Also, could someone with competence add a grails-3.0 tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the authors of postgresql-extensions. At this moment the plugin is not compatible with Grails 3.0. We need to wait until the Grails team publish an updated documentation of how to migrate the plugins from 2.x to 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

For mongodb use:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:4.0.0.M1'
```